# fail2ban - Additional regex for sshd filter

Tags: fail2ban

I am currently trying to catch failed SSH login attempts with certificate based authentication (certificate correct but wrong password) using fail2ban version 0.11.2-2 (running on Debian 11).

Therefore I created a new file `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.local` with the content

```
[Definition]
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            ^%(__prefix_line)sConnection closed by authenticating user <F-USER>.+</F-USER> <HOST> port \d+ \[preauth\]$
```

so that the filter rule is not overwritten in future updates.

To test this, I caused the situation myself a few times and can confirm with `sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.local` that the filter finds the log entries:

> 23. [88] ^(?:[])?\s*(?:<[^.]+.[^.]+>\s+)?(?:\S+\s+)?(?:kernel:\s?[
>     *\d+.\d+]:?\s+)?(?:@vserver_\S+\s+)?(?:(?:(?:[\d+])?:\s+[[(]?sshd(?:(\S+))?[])]?:?|[[(]?sshd(?:(\S+))?[])]?:?(?:[\d+])?:?)\s+)?(?:[ID
>     \d+ \S+]\s+)?Connection closed by authenticating user
>     .+  port \d+ [preauth]$

But nothing happens on the filter status:

```
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|   - File list:        /var/log/auth.log
 - Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
    - Banned IP list:
```

Do you have any ideas what is not working here or where else I should look?

Answer (score 0):

> can confirm with `fail2ban-regex ... /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.local` that the filter finds the log entries

The default filter (in mode `normal`) will ignore it with other already available RE which is a helper to consider IP of the session (for other messages happening in the same session but without IP) and it stops by [first RE](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/095aeda8407b433098df35424cde2764a09566a6/config/filter.d/sshd.conf#L71) matching the message. Whereas `fail2ban-regex` shows any matching REs, also duplicates.

So you'd also see `20) [88] ...` in the output.
As well as `Lines: N lines, 88 ignored, X matched, Y missed`.

To achieve this correctly (without your local modifications at all):

1. either set `filter = %(known/filter)s[publickey=any]` in `sshd` jail (since your version must already support it, see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/discussions/3176#discussioncomment-1768538 for more information).
2. or simply set `mode = aggressive` in `sshd` jail.

To handle this correctly (with your local modifications):

3. either rewrite `mdre-normal-other`, for example in jail.local:

```
[sshd]
filter = %(known/filter)s[mdre-normal-other=""]
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            ^Connection closed by ...
```

4. or write your custom RE before original REs... Just note that newest fail2ban versions would reorder them (https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/3007):

```
failregex = ^Connection closed by ...
            %(known/failregex)s
```

And don't use `%(__prefix_line)s` in `failregex`, because it is already handled in `prefregex`, so one needs to write it like here:

```
- ^%(__prefix_line)sConnection ...
+ ^Connection ...
```